# How can I use physics to create a bobble head?

Tags: physics

I'd like to create a bobble head type set up.  A smaller cube (the head) slightly higher than a larger cube (the body).  When the smaller cube is hit by another physics object I want it to behave like it is on a spring and get knocked back and forth and eventually settle down with damping.

I've tried using the physics generic spring but I don't seem to get the behavior I am looking for (head falls down and hangs by spring).
I've also tried creating a third object above the head (and parented to the body)  and have the head hanging from that object using a spring.  This partly works but the head can start doing wild spins and not return to it's normal facing forward position.
I've consider using more than one generic spring (one to hold up and one to help return it to facing forward) but I think I must be missing a more simple solution.

Note: I do have the head and body connected with a point connection to maintain same distance throughout.

Just a brief description of best options to accomplish this would be appreciated.